# Select distinct from a table foreach value from another

Tags: sql-server

I have a view that gets the status for each category for each venue.

I need to display all of the above, but only the latest in the status for each category for each venue.

A general idea could be, for each item in a shop, there is a status. So for the *cucumbers*, *letters*, and *tomatoes* in shop A, the status would be *good good bad* respectively. Same for shop B, C etc. Now these statuses can be updated at any time - but only the latest update should be displayed.

I have tried to create a view such as the following:

```
SELECT
       dbo.vwVenues.HospitalID
     , dbo.vwVenues.Hospital AS hospitalName
     , dbo.tblVenueStatus.id AS statusId
     , dbo.tblVenueStatusName.statusName
     , dbo.tblVenueStatusCategories.categoryName
     , dbo.tblVenueStatus.dateAdded AS statusDateAdded
     , dbo.tblVenueStatus.loggedBy AS statusLoggedBy
     , dbo.tblVenueStatusNotes.noteContent
     , dbo.tblVenueStatusNotes.dateAdded AS noteDateAdded
     , dbo.tblVenueStatusNotes.removed AS noteRemoved
     , dbo.tblVenueStatus.resolved AS statusResolved
     , dbo.tblVenueStatus.resolveDate AS statusResolveDate
     , dbo.tblVenueStatus.removed AS statusRemoved
     , dbo.tblVenueStatus.dateRemoved AS statusRemovedDate
     , dbo.tblVenueStatus.categoryId
FROM 
    dbo.tblVenueStatusName
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblVenueStatusNotes
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblVenueStatus
    ON dbo.tblVenueStatusNotes.id = dbo.tblVenueStatus.noteId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblVenueStatusCategories
    ON dbo.tblVenueStatus.categoryId = dbo.tblVenueStatusCategories.id
    ON dbo.tblVenueStatusName.id = dbo.tblVenueStatus.statusNameId
  FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.vwVenues
    ON dbo.tblVenueStatus.venuId = dbo.vwVenues.HospitalID
```

I get all the venues, but I get **all** the statuses for each category, instead of just the latest. Even trying to phrase the question right was hard - so my current search yeilded nothing.

Could anyone please help?
**Edit**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblVenueStatus](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [statusNameId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [venuId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [categoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [loggedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [noteId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dateAdded] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [resolved] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [resolveDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [removed] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [dateRemoved] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblSiteVenuStatus] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblVenueStatusCategories](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [categoryName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [categoryDescription] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblVenueStatusCategories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblVenueStatusName](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [statusName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [statusDescription] [nchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblVenuStatusName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblVenueStatusNotes](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [noteContent] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [dateAdded] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [removed] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [dateRemoved] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblVenueStatusNotes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Desired Output will be:

```
Venu Name  |  Category 1 Status  |  Category 2 Status
```

Comment: Simplify the query and provide sample data for source records and desired output in tabular form. That might help you to get help faster.

Comment: I doubt I can simplify a query that gets only what I need. If I take anything away, it might throw any correct answer off. I'll update my question with the remaining advice.

Comment: @Devart - I copy pasted the query... There is no error here.

Comment: @Devart It seems the misplaced `ON` does work. Edited so it's easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. It's largely sumerised because of what you said you needed to see in your sample.  Try this and let me know if it helps. You can add other columns you need here, It is taking the latest status in each category for each hospital, and showing all hospitals and categories in a easily readable grid.

```
SELECT * FROM           
(
    SELECT VwV.HospitalID, vwV.Hospital, ISNULL(vStatusName.statusName, '') AS statusName, vStatusCategories.categoryName 
    FROM            
    (
        SELECT topStatus.HospitalID, topStatus.categoryId, sta2.id 
        FROM            
        (
            SELECT HospitalID, categoryId, MAX(sta.dateAdded) AS DateAdded 
            FROM vwVenues 
            INNER JOIN tblVenueStatus sta ON sta.venuId = dbo.vwVenues.HospitalID
            GROUP BY HospitalID, categoryId
        ) topStatus 
        INNER JOIN tblVenueStatus sta2 ON sta2.dateAdded = topStatus.DateAdded AND sta2.venuId = topStatus.HospitalID) Statuss 
        FULL OUTER JOIN vwVenues vwV ON vwV.HospitalID = Statuss.HospitalID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblVenueStatus vStatus ON vStatus.id = Statuss.id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblVenueStatusName vStatusName ON vStatusName.id = vStatus.statusNameId 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblVenueStatusCategories vStatusCategories ON vStatus.categoryId = vStatusCategories.id AND vStatusName.id = vStatus.statusNameId 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblVenueStatusNotes vStatusNotes ON vStatusNotes.id = vStatus.noteId
) AS s     
PIVOT (MIN(StatusName) 
FOR [CategoryName] IN ([Category1],[Category2])) AS PTbl
```

Comment: I'm sorry that me typing a Helpful answer on my phone is not up to your standard.

Comment: Not sure about this question, but, in general, you can probably get a few more upvotes by formatting code properly (assuming you care about that sort of thing). That's all I'm saying.